# Did I correctly apprehend this description of a binary function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

From Wikipedia,

> $f$ is a binary function if there exists $X,Y,Z$  such that $f: X × Y \mapsto Z$ ....
>
> ...one may represent a binary function as a subset of the Cartesian product $X × Y × Z$, where $(x,y,z)$ belongs to the subset if and only if $f(x,y) = z$.

So then

Suppose

- $f = 4(x,y)$
- $X = \{1,2,3\}$
- $Y = \{4,5,6\}$

Then the range, $Z$, is $\{(4,16), (4,20), (4,24), (8,16), (8,20), (8,24), (12,16), (12,20), (12,24)\}$

and
$(x,y,z)$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X × Y × Z$, which equals $\{(1,4,(4,16)), (1,4,(4,20)), (1,4,(4,24))... (1,4,(12,24)), (2,4,(4,16)), (2,4,(4,20))...(2,4,(12,24)), ...(3,6,(12,24))\}$

Is that correct?

Comment: Looks right. Note you can have $Z$ here be any collection of ordered pairs which includes the range you have computed, and still have a binary function. In your example the binary function happens to be onto (and one to one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And as coffeemath [puts it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723508/did-i-correctly-apprehend-this-description-of-a-binary-function#comment1512344_723508):

> Note you can have $Z$ here be any collection of ordered pairs which includes the range you have computed, and still have a binary function. In your example the binary function happens to be onto (and one to one).